# Using <element>.select() to highlight text input in firefox triggers page jump to location of selected field

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a "copy to clipboard" function on my personal portfolio so it's easier to access my email

This is my onclick html which is displayed at the top of the page

```
<p id="emailHover" style= "cursor: pointer;" onclick="copyText()"> myemail@email.com</p>
```

This is my transparent (hidden input field won't work) input field at the bottom of the page

```
<input id="email" type="text" value="myemail@email.com" style="border: none; color: transparent;" readonly>
```

And this is my JavaScript function that executes on click

```
function copyText() {
    let clipboard = document.getElementById("email")
    let emailHover = document.getElementById("emailHover")
    clipboard.select()
    document.execCommand("copy")
    emailHover.title = "Copied to clipboard!"

}
```

On Chrome everything works as intended. The page jump only occurs in Firefox. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way does a hidden input not work?

Comment: I believe for .select() to work properly the element needs to be rendered on the screen